# "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from client.jar" in a possible malware .jar file?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, program-entry-point, malware

I found a Client.jar file on a customer's computer, containing two .class files which I could decompile to this two files:

[Client.java](http://pastebin.com/yYCC2E89)

[I.java](http://pastebin.com/a684LJcG)

Moreover there's a I.gif which is obviously no GIF looking at it with a hex editor.

They're obviously obfuscated and I'm not into Java that much. I tried to run in in a VM but it tells me **"Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from Client.jar"**

Might be, that the main class is not in the manifest, but how to fix this? **Does this mean, it could not be run on the customer's computer?**

There's also a META-INF folder containing the files MANIFEST.MF, ME.DSA, ME.SF.

MANIFEST.MF looks like that:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_20 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Name: Client.class
SHA1-Digest: ex7bAth9HYUTIi8EcpeOc1OsVMg=

Name: I/I.class
SHA1-Digest: 0H6A7/XmOCNhayPI9TwC45Mky4s=

Name: I/I.gif
SHA1-Digest: AzzSpXaRFMYvtYJvrnFsHQDvJkE=
```

I would like to analyse this further by running it in sandboxie or VM, what does the error mean how can I run it?

It's obviously some sort of malware, so only experts should answer this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide us with the I.gif? Obviously with a strong warning for anyone thinking of using it... I'd like to initialize the `I` class and see what info it extracts from that file. Don't worry, I'll be careful :)

Comment: As you can see in the source code, a string is build from the I.gif and used as url for a http connection.

Comment: @Stephan Yes, I know. But I want to know where it points to, or what file it's trying to write.

Comment: @G_H there it is: http://www.filedropper.com/i_13 Please let me know what happens and how I can analyse it myself.

Comment: @puerta Hmm, I've tried downloading it twice but it always gives me a 0-byte file.

Comment: @G_H it's 44 bytes large, I posted the bytes here: http://pastebin.com/WBcN93bk

Comment: @puerta Thanks. I'm updating my answer... will only take a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to start a Java application from a jar file, it must know which class forms the entry point. That class needs a `main` method. It can either be specified in the jar's `MANIFEST.MF` file, or specified when running (for example, from the command line).

The decompiled classes (which do indeed seem to be obfuscated) don't contain a main method. So this wouldn't be a jar that's runnable as a stand-alone app. However, `Client` extends `Applet`, indicating this was intended to be run as a web applet in a browser. Check [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html) to find out how you can run it.

Probably best to run it through a bunch of virus/spyware/adware scanners if you suspect it's malicious.

**EDIT**: after altering the code and running it with the gif (**don't do this if you're not certain about what you're doing!**), I've come to the conclusion that this is what happens:

First, the "gif" is gonna be decoded in a somewhat round-about way. Its first three bytes determine the size of a byte array that the rest of the gif is gonna be loaded into. Parts of this byte array are used to construct Strings that are used in the applet.

When the applet is initialized, it's gonna fetch the value of applet parameter `AMLMAFOIEA`. This parameter needs to be set in the HTML that contains the applet, so the value is going to be dependent on the page that the applet is run from. [Here's the details of how this is set.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

After that, it's gonna get the value of environment variable `TEMP`. In my case, this pointed to `AppData\Local\Temp` in my user directory. It's gonna append `\JavaLoad.exe` to this and use that path to create a `FileOutputStream`, so obviously it's trying to write out a JavaLoad.exe file in your temp folder.

It will then establish a HTTP connection to a URL specified by the `AMLMAFOIEA` applet parameter, setting its request method to `GET`. A stream will be opened from the connection and its contents dumped into the JavaLoad.exe file.

The constant repetition of the code block

```
  if ((this.b == this.c) && (this.b + I.I(1) == this.c + I.I(1)))
  {
    this.b = I.I(4);
    this.c = I.I(6);
    this.b = this.c;
  }
```

seems to do nothing at all. It might have been added by an obfuscator to throw you off track since this doesn't seem to have any functional impact whatsoever. All the important stuff is done outside of those tests and the fields `b` and `c` don't ever seem to be used for anything really functional, only field `a` is used to hold the target URL String.

So, in conclusion, this does seem very suspicious. But what URL it truly tries to download stuff from will depend on the applet's environment. Unfortunately this doesn't point us to any true source. Maybe this is a general trojan client that's intended for use by anyone who wishes to deliver a malicious payload via a site with applets. Since applets run in a sandbox with limited permissions, I'm not certain if this'd work at all. I also don't know how it will eventually run JavaLoad.exe. I suppose it relies on some other process that expects this file to exist, maybe something normally harmless.

This was interesting. Thanks for the resources. I suggest you don't try to run any of this stuff yourself if you're not a Java developer and don't know how to take the dangerous portions out of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The MANIFEST.MF does not contain a main class attribute, as you can see in your post. This could be a troyan downloader, it definitly opens a httpconnection, downloads files and executes them. The gif file seems to contain the url.

I would strongly recommend to delete this jar and scan the computer for malware! Do not try to execute it.